# odoo 15 database (zip includes file store) restore error

Tags: restore, odoo-15

When I try to restore database backup to another server (digital ocean to test server on aws), showing an error like this, I tried to change odoo base to same as of the live server.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/odoo14/odoo14-server/odoo/api.py", line 792, in get
field_cache = field_cache[record.env.cache_key(field)]
KeyError: (None,)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/odoo14/odoo14-server/odoo/fields.py", line 972, in __get__
value = env\.cache\.get\(record,\ self\)
\ \ File\ "/odoo14/odoo14\-server/odoo/api\.py",\ line\ 796,\ in\ get
\ \ \ \ raise\ CacheMiss\(record,\ field\)
odoo\.exceptions\.CacheMiss:\ 'res\.users\(20,\)\.image_128'

During\ handling\ of\ the\ above\ exception,\ another\ exception\ occurred:

Traceback\ \(most\ recent\ call\ last\):
\ \ File\ "/odoo14/odoo14\-server/odoo/api\.py",\ line\ 792,\ in\ get
\ \ \ \ field_cache\ =\ field_cache\[record\.env\.cache_key\(field\)\]
KeyError:\ \(None,\)

During\ handling\ of\ the\ above\ exception,\ another\ exception\ occurred:

Traceback\ \(most\ recent\ call\ last\):
\ \ File\ "/odoo14/odoo14\-server/odoo/fields\.py",\ line\ 972,\ in\ __get__
\ \ \ \ value\ =\ env\.cache\.get\(record,\ self\)
\ \ File\ "/odoo14/odoo14\-server/odoo/api\.py",\ line\ 796,\ in\ get
\ \ \ \ raise\ CacheMiss\(record,\ field\)
odoo\.exceptions\.CacheMiss:\ 'res\.partner\(12809,\)\.image_128'

During\ handling\ of\ the\ above\ exception,\ another\ exception\ occurred:

Traceback\ \(most\ recent\ call\ last\):
\ \ File\ "/odoo14/odoo14\-server/odoo/api\.py",\ line\ 792,\ in\ get
\ \ \ \ field_cache\ =\ field_cache\[record\.env\.cache_key\(field\)\]
KeyError:\ \(None,\ None\)

During\ handling\ of\ the\ above\ exception,\ another\ exception\ occurred:

Traceback\ \(most\ recent\ call\ last\):
\ \ File\ "/odoo14/odoo14\-server/odoo/fields\.py",\ line\ 972,\ in\ __get__
\ \ \ \ value\ =\ env\.cache\.get\(record,\ self\)
\ \ File\ "/odoo14/odoo14\-server/odoo/api\.py",\ line\ 796,\ in\ get
\ \ \ \ raise\ CacheMiss\(record,\ field\)
odoo\.exceptions\.CacheMiss:\ 'ir\.attachment\(321,\)\.datas'

During\ handling\ of\ the\ above\ exception,\ another\ exception\ occurred:

Traceback\ \(most\ recent\ call\ last\):
\ \ File\ "/odoo14/odoo14\-server/odoo/api\.py",\ line\ 792,\ in\ get
\ \ \ \ field_cache\ =\ field_cache\[record\.env\.cache_key\(field\)\]
KeyError:\ \(None,\)

During\ handling\ of\ the\ above\ exception,\ another\ exception\ occurred:

Traceback\ \(most\ recent\ call\ last\):
\ \ File\ "/odoo14/odoo14\-server/odoo/fields\.py",\ line\ 972,\ in\ __get__
\ \ \ \ value\ =\ env\.cache\.get\(record,\ self\)
\ \ File\ "/odoo14/odoo14\-server/odoo/api\.py",\ line\ 796,\ in\ get
\ \ \ \ raise\ CacheMiss\(record,\ field\)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'ir.attachment(321,).raw'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/odoo14/odoo14-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 105, in _file_read
with open(full_path, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/odoo14/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/APL_2.0/c5/c54d3d5e2b1320083bf5378b7c195b0985fa04c1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem commonly caused by failed process during the backup. When you try to backup a database, the server is pulling out a .dump files and a filestore folder which is the place where user files like .pdf and images are saved. Both files later be combined into a .zip file.

Now, when you restoring your database, it shows an error of :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/odoo14/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/APL_2.0/c5/c54d3d5e2b1320083bf5378b7c195b0985fa04c1'
```

It seems like database is currently restored successfully, but it cannot read the `c54d3d5e2b1320083bf5378b7c195b0985fa04c1` file inside filestore folder properly. It might be missing, or not having enough privilege for reading and writing into your filestore inside the machine.

I wrote an [article](https://www.projectflakes.com/2022/04/how-to-backup-and-restore-large-odoo.html) on how to backup and restore database especially a large size ones.